# setting up travis-ci for multiple sub project on one repo

Tags: travis-ci

I have several folders in one github project where each has a different .travis.yml file.

What is the correct way to setup travis-ci so that I can specify which folder / sub-project to build?

I can add `before_script: cd function` but is there a way to trigger the build only based function being updated on the `develop` branch - basically i don't want to trigger the build if i update a sub-folder.

Any advise is much appreciated

Comment: did you find a solution to  this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list of branches to build:

```
branches:
 only:
 - develop
 - release
 - master
```

And do different steps for each branch:

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: bash -x deploy/script_deploy.sh develop
    on:
      branch: develop
```

Do you need something else?